# Haskell: "Append" type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

From what I understand [`Foldable`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Data-Foldable.html) basically represents structures that have a number of elements of the same type that can be iterated over, i.e. lists, maps, sets, etc.

Is there a class like `Appendable` or `Insertable` which basically represents structures one can add elements to? Of course there would be no guarantee of the order of which elements are retrieved.

I'd rather not create a class myself if there already is one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at the [Data.Collections](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/collections-api/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Collections.html) package. It contains the `Unfoldable` typeclass with the following methods:

```
class Unfoldable c i | c -> i where
  insert :: i -> c -> c
  empty :: c
  singleton :: i -> c
```

It also provides the `insertMany` and `insertManySorted` methods, to insert all the elements from a `Foldable` into an `Unfoldable`.

If you make your type an instance of both `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` then you can both insert and retrieve elements from it.

Answer (score 3):

I think insertion itself isn't really a sensible concept.  There are better ways to generalize this.  For example `Alternative` is a sensible type class there.  You get `pure` for singletons and some generic *union* operation in the form of `<|>`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a class like `Appendable` or `Insertable` which basically represents structures one can add elements to?

You want to be clearer on what you mean by "add elements."  Because there are two ways this could go:

```
class Insertable c where
    -- Add one element to the collection.
    insert :: a -> c a -> c a

class Appendable c where
    -- Append a collection to another.
    append :: c a -> c a -> c a
```

The latter, you will note, does not support adding a lone `a` to the collection unless you add an operation like this:

```
class Pointed c where
    singleton :: a -> c a
```

Note that if you have `Appendable` and `Pointed` instances you can define an `Insertable`:

```
instance (Appendable c, Pointed c) => Insertable c where
    insert x xs = append (singleton x) xs
```

The `Insertable` class, together with operations for actually accessing the collection's elements (e.g. the `Foldable` class), can likewise be used to define an `Appendable` instance.

In any case, my mock `Appendable` class above is really just [`Monoid`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html) in disguise.  My `Insertable` can likewise be seen as a disguised version of Chris Taylor's suggested `Unfoldable` class.  I'd go with the [`Collection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/collections-api/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Collections.html#g:3) class from that package, though, which combines both `Unfoldable` with `Foldable`.

Comment: +1 for "really just Monoid". The Appendable class doesn't add anything over it IMO, unless I'm missing something.